# how to pass a url as a "url parameter" in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, url-parameters

In my express app I have a router listening to `api/shorten/`:

```
    router.get('api/shorten/:longUrl', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.params.longUrl);
    }
```

When I use something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/shorten/www.udemy.com
```

I get `www.udemy.com` which is what I expect.

But when I use:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/shorten/http://www.udemy.com
```

I get a 404 error.

I want to get `http://www.udemy.com` when I access `req.params.parameter`.

Comment: You must pass url as body or at least in query param and not appending to the original url itself. The error you are getting is because browser will filter it out

Comment: You have to encode the URL you are attaching as characters like `:` are not allowed anywhere except in the protocol so can't be used in the path of the URL.

Comment: @binariedMe - That's the not true. It can be in the path if encoded properly.

Comment: Agreed. I personally won't prefer encoding as you need to recreate url on server side. Instead passing this as query param or in body is easy

Comment: I always use encodeUriComponent and pass urls in the query string. Decode using decodeUriComponent

Comment: please look at this example. you can pass the url as it is whithout encoding .. I am wondering how to do that ? https://little-url.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Those are not legal URIs.  The `:` character must be encoded when it appears anywhere other than in the first protocol.  See section 2.2. of the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're still looking for a solution to this problem. Perhaps just in case someone else is trying to figure out the same thing, this is a simple solution to your problem:

```
app.get('/new/*', function(req, res) {

  // Grab params that are attached on the end of the /new/ route
  var url = req.params[0];
```

This way you don't have to sweat about any forward slashes being mistaken for routes or directories, it will grab everything after /new/.

Comment: Thanks @Allan. I have found this solution already but your answer will be helpful for others who are facing the same problem. I will accept it since it was the answer that I used to solve my problem.

Comment: Glorious! thanks from the future!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `encodeURIComponent` in the client, and `decodeURIComponent` in the express server, this will encode all the not allowed characters from the url parameter like `:` and `/`

Comment: I'm designing an API so I have no control of the client side .. I can not encode it in the client, I have to handle it in the server only

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape as so:

```
escape("http://www.google.com")
```

Which returns:

```
"http%3A//www.google.com"
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I want to solve it without encoding it, I want to pass it as it is and handle that in the server side.

Comment: Alright change your route to
     "api/shorten/:longUrl*"

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that if you pass another params like `?param=some_param` into your "url paramter" it will not show up in `req.params[0]`. 
Instead you can just use `req.url` property.

Comment: Or you can look at the complete `req.params` array! If you're looking for a parameter with a particular key, you could use `const paramKeys = Object.keys(req.params)` to get the keys in the order in which they appear and then `const matchingIndex = paramKeys.findIndex('the-query-key-im-looking-for')` to find the index of the parameter, and then finally `req.params[matchingIndex` to get the value.